# How to detect multiple keys entered in c# keydown event of textbox?

Tags: c#, silverlight, keyboard

I want to design a **numeric textbox** in silverlight.

I have added **keydown event** of TextBox to **handle the keypress**.

Inside event I validate the key entered in the textbox.

event as follows

```
  private void TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.Validate(sender,e))
            e.Handled = true;
    }
```

function Validate as follows

```
  private bool Validate(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Key == Key.Enter) //accept enter and tab
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (e.Key == Key.Tab)
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (e.Key < Key.D0 || e.Key > Key.D9) //accept number on alphnumeric key
            if (e.Key < Key.NumPad0 || e.Key > Key.NumPad9) //accept number fomr NumPad
                if (e.Key != Key.Back) //accept backspace
                    return false;

        return true;
    }
```

I am not able to detect shift and Key.D0 to Key.D1 i.e.

**SHIFT + 1** which returns "**!**"

**SHIFT + 3** returns "**#**" like wise any other special keys.

I dont want user to enter special character  in to textbox.

How do i handle this keys event??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Silverlight, I don't think there are any `Modifier`s in the `KeyEventArgs` class but instead in `Keyboard`:

```
    public void KeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control && e.Key == Key.D0)
        {
            ControlZero();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. KeyEventArgs does not contain the modifiers.

Answer (score 0):

`e` should have a property on it that will tell you if Shift, Control or Alt are pressed.  `e.Modifiers` can also give you additional information about which additional modifier keys have been pressed.

To cancel the character you can set `e.Handled` to `True`, which will cause the control to ignore the keypress.

Answer (score 0):

```
textBox2.Text = string.Empty;
textBox2.Text = e.Modifiers.ToString() + " + " + e.KeyCode.ToString();
```